# Maven won't compile the classes in test folder

Tags: java, maven, testing, pom.xml

I'm trying to have some end-to-end test for the component I'm developing using Java. So, these classes in `test` are not Unit Tests, and I only want to run them as a normal Java class.

I have my sources in the `src\main\java` folder and the tests inside `src\test\java`. The test has two Java classes, one is a util class and the other one extends a class in `main` and also has the main method. **Ultimately, I need to run this main method**.

I created two pom files, one for the main project and one for running the test. The only difference in the test pom file was the `mainClass` property. 
When I had the test classes inside `src\main\java`, maven compiles them and **I was able to run them without any issue**.

Because having tests inside the `src\main\java` folder is a bad practice, I wanted to move it to the `src\test\java` folder. But then it doesn't work. It compiles the project but doesn't compile the test classes (obviously because now it's not inside the `src\main\java` folder). So I added the `test` to the classpath scope in the test pom file as below.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.my.company.project.MyTestClass</mainClass>
        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But this doesn't work.

So I tried the [solution](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html) provided by maven itself, but it's the same. It creates the jar file with my test class as the main class in the manifest file. But there are is no such class, nor classes from the `main` inside of the jar file. And I get the below error when running the jar file.

```
Could not find or load main class com.my.company.project.MyTestClass
```

My end goal is to be able to compile and run my Test class (to test the main class) using maven.

Can you suggest me a way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>

    <developers>
        ...
    </developers>

    <dependencies>
       ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0</version>
                </plugin>
                ...
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.my.company.project.MyClass</mainClass>
                <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.my.company.project.MyClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-verbose</arg>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT 2:**

According to the comment from @notionquest, I updated the POM file. Now the test classes are getting compiled, but not available inside the jar file. So, it still gives me the error:

```java
Error: Could not find or load main class com.trivago.visual.debezium.test.ChangeDataCaptureSenderTest
```

Comment: You may need to show the full pom. This is a trivial one. Maven should compile both source class and test class. Probably, the test classes are not included in the artifacts (jar or war) generated.

Comment: `src\tests\java` should be `src\test\java`, could that already solve the issue?

Comment: @notionquest : Added the pom file. I wouldn't mind if my tests are not inside the final jar, but I need to run it (preferably as a jar), because it will connect a Docker DB.

Comment: @f1sh : It was a typo.

Comment: If this is your pom I'm not astonished that your code will not being compiled cause the packaging: pom . which is wrong for a project which should produce a jar file...etc. So you should change the `<packaging>pom</packaging>` to `<packaging>jar</packaging>`...

Comment: @khmarbaise : Thanks a lot for pointing that out. Now it gave a lot of compile errors and I fixed them. And the class file of my test is now inside the `target\test_classes` but no jar file is created.

Comment: How have you called Maven? `mvn clean package` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I decided to add the tests inside `src` and exclude them in the deployment pom file.